# why does array.length give "Uncaught TypeError: array.length is not a function" error in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the last element of an array using Javascript which is the last "word" in the text of an HTML  Tag.

```
<select name="resultsSelectionBox" id="resultsSelectionBox" onchange="myFunction()"></select>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var selectedValue = document.getElementById("resultsSelectionBox").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + selectedValue;
    var separatedSelectedValue = selectedValue.split(" ");
    var lastItem = separatedSelectedValue[separatedSelectedValue.length() - 1]
    console.log(separatedSelectedValue);
}
```

The variable separatedSelectedValue is an array created by splitting the contents of selectedValue. When I try to run the code, there is an error underlined for the line  "separatedSelectedValue.length()" which has this message "Method expression is not of Function type".

And if I try to run the code, I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: separatedSelectedValue.length is not a function" I thought .length was a function of Arrays in JS, and if not how do I get the length of an array?

Comment: Because `.length` is not a function, it's a property.

Comment: Q: Why does array.length give “Uncaught TypeError: array.length is not a function"?  Because `myarray.length()` *ISN'T* a function!  You probably meant `myarray.length`, which is a valid *PROPERTY* of the JS prototype [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `separatedSelectedValue.length()`, which means to use length as a function, but it's a property, so you will need `.length` without the `()` to get its value.

**Use this**

```
var lastItem = separatedSelectedValue[separatedSelectedValue.length - 1]
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: thanks, this worked I didn't know that it was a property and not a function as in other languages